# VBA Macro - copy paste multiple worksheets based on value on reference table

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple worksheets:

```
1) Agent Sales
Name | Product | Sales
A | XX | $100
B | XX | $200
C | YY | $150
A | YY | $400


2) Agent Expense
Name | Product | Expense
A | XX | $10
B | XX | $20
C | YY | $15
A | YY | $80
```

The idea is to create a report on a separate worksheet per agent comparing them against the other agents for every single product. For example for Agent A:

```
>     Sales
>     Name | Product | Sales
>     A | XX | $100
>     B | XX | $200
>     
>     Expense
>     Name | Product | Sales
>     A | XX | $10
>     B | XX | $10
>     
>     
>     Sales
>     Name | Product | Sales
>     A | YY | $400
>     C | YY | $150
>     
>     Expense
>     Name | Product | Sales
>     A | YY | $80
>     C | YY | $15
```

I'm just trying to learn VBA and my first step to the problem is to have the copy and paste function working using autofiltered. Here's my code so far:
Sub Test()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales")
ws.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="A"
ws.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="XX"
ws.Range("A2:C2", Range("A2:C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Expense")
ws2.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="A"
ws2.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="XX"
ws2.Range("A2:C2", Range("A2:C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

It returned a runtime error 1004 - method of range of object failed.

However, if i only copy paste just the sales table, the code worked.

I saw posts where VBA might delete the data on the clipboard, but given the sales table was successfully pasted, I'm not sure why second one giving out error.

Appreciate all the help/ideas.

Comment: see answer below how to get rid of the Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your following code line:

```
ws2.Range("A2:C2", Range("A2:C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
```

The `Range` is missing the Sheet reference, you need to add ***ws2***, like this:

```
ws2.Range("A2:C2", ws2.Range("A2:C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
```

Copy the full code below, you will not get any errors (tested on my PC with your sample data you uploaded)

```
Sub TestCopyPaste()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales")

ws.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="A"
ws.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="XX"
ws.Range("A2:C2", ws.Range("A2:C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Expense")

ws2.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="A"
ws2.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="XX"
ws2.Range("A2:C2", ws2.Range("A2:C2").End(xlDown)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the `Field:=1` filter because you are trying to group by products not name and products.

[image]

```
Sub TestCopyPaste()
    Dim NextRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim Name As String, Product As String
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim ExpenseRange As Range

    Worksheets("Report").Cells.Clear

    For x = 2 To Worksheets("Sales").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Name = Worksheets("Sales").Cells(x, 1)
        Product = Worksheets("Sales").Cells(x, 2)

        If Not dict.Exists(Product) Then
            NextRow = Worksheets("Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If NextRow > 1 Then NextRow = NextRow + 2

            getFilteredData(Worksheets("Sales"), Name, Product).Copy Worksheets("Report").Cells(NextRow, 1)

            Set ExpenseRange = getFilteredData(Worksheets("Expense"), Name, Product)

            If Not ExpenseRange Is Nothing Then
                NextRow = Worksheets("Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2
                ExpenseRange.Copy Worksheets("Report").Cells(NextRow, 1)
            End If

            dict.Add Product, vbNullString
        End If
    Next

    Worksheets("Report").Columns.AutoFit

End Sub

Function getFilteredData(ws As Worksheet, Name As String, Product As String)
     With ws
        '.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Name
        .Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Product
        Set getFilteredData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi Thomas - i'm trying to figure out the logic you put in place in your code but I didint see any paste function being used at all? The reason is now I want to paste but keep the destination formatting, and not sure where to put the paste special function

Comment: `ExpenseRange.Copy Worksheets("Report").Cells(NextRow, 1)` This line does a full copy and paste; including data and formats.